# Extend Docker Environment created by WP-ENV

Tags: wordpress, docker, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using the [@wordpress/env](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-env/) package. Unfortunatly I did not find any information on how I can add environment variables to the generated docker container.

Is there a possibility to add environment variables that can be used by a custom plugins within wordpress?

My first intention was to configure the wp-config.json but that does not seem to give that option.

Reading the question below I found the solution to modify the docker-compose from wp-env. I do not think that this is nice soltuion because it has to be done manually and can not be configured with the wp-env option. In this regard I am looking for a better solution.

[How to extend docker environment generated by wp-env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665946/how-to-extend-docker-environment-generated-by-wp-env)